# Modelica for python/matlab/simulink/maple users?

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, maple, modelica

I am trying to learn Modelica coming from a Python/MATLAB/Simulink/Maple background.   Are there any resources for learning Modelica for people with experience in other languages/environments?

When I learned Python from the context of a MATLAB background, I found a lot of help in [NumPy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).  Are there any similar resources for learning Modelica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something to do with Modelica during my Master thesis period.

You can for sure have a look at this forum

http://www.modelica-forum.com/forums/

which is the official forum for Modelica language.

Furthermore, you can easily consult the following webpage:

https://modelica.org/

If it's not enough you might consider the idea of purchasing the textbook

> Peter Fritzson: Principles of Object-Oriented Modeling and Simulation
>   with Modelica 2.1, 939 pages,Wiley-IEEE Press, ISBN 0-471-471631.

I believe this should be enough for a first dive into Modelica.

I hope it helps.